# Django faster way to store images locally from URL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am working on a website where I want to populate product data from an external API. This api has hundreds of products data, and each product has dozens of variants. Each product and data have their images which I'm using Django's ImageField from models to store locally. Now the problem is that there are well over 15000 images, and it is taking forever to do populate the images data. Here is the structure of API:

```
{
...
Single Product Image: ...
    { Product Variant1: ..., [list of 4 images] }
    { Product Variant2: ..., [list of 4 images] }
    { Product Variant3: ..., [list of 4 images] }
}
```

Each product has somewhere from 10-50 variations. Here is what I have done. For variation images, I'm using a many-to-one relationship table to store all the images of each variant:

models.py:

```
class ProductsVariation(models.Model):
    ....

class VariationImages(models.Model):
    prd_id = models.ForeignKey(ProductsVariation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'product_variation')
```

get_products.py:

```
from django.core.files import File
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import requests

for product in api_data: #Loop over main product
    ...
    main_product_request = requests.get(product['IMAGE_NAME'])

    main_img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    main_img_temp.write(main_product_request.content)
    main_img_temp.flush()

    main_product.prd_img.save(product['GENERIC_NAME'] + ".jpg", File(main_img_temp), save=True)
    main_product.save()
    # Populate this product's variants
    for variants in product['Product']: # Loop through each variant of this product
        ....
        for img in variants['Images']: # For each variant, save their images to DB
            vari = VariationImages.objects.create(prd_id=prd_variant)

            vari_product_request = requests.get(img)

            vari_img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
            vari_img_temp.write(vari_product_request.content)
            vari_img_temp.flush()

            vari.img.save(product['GENERIC_NAME'] + ".jpg", File(vari_img_temp), save=True)
            vari.save()
```

Just to clarify, the main_product image and variantions images go in separete tables in the DB. I could not find any other way to store the images. Maybe there is a better way of storing images from API? Or maybe it's a problem of how I'm doing it? I do not know how to optimize this.

EDIT: After more testing, I am quite sure the bottleneck is coming from files being saved to the disk. I tried saving the files directly to the local storage from the API urls and it seems to be very slow. It is taking approximately 30-40 seconds to store around 500 images. I tried using urllib.request.urlretrieve, Pillow and dload, BytesIO but all of them have pretty much the same result.

Comment: What DB backend are you using? Have you looked into the bulk insert and update functions that may be available?

Comment: I'm using Postgresql. I have looked into bulk insertion, but I don't know how I would keep these objects saved before the loop goes to the next object in list. Or am I understanding bulk operations wrong?

Comment: I think the problem may be from requests.get(img), which gets the image content from URL and writes the file to disk for each individual image. I tried using bulk insertion just now and it did not make any difference.

Comment: 500 images in 30 seconds (approx 16/second) over HTTP doesn't seem bad to me. Also, the image or API server might be throttling your connections because you're sending too many requests too fast. (Supposing if it's a network related bottleneck and not, as you've mentioned, a disk related one.)